# can not ping any hostname

Tags: centos, ping

I recently got a server from a company for new mail service configuration but
now i have a amazing problem!
"ping google.com" not working and returned "ping: unknown host google.com" , but ping 8.8.8.8 works good.
i have checked the resolv.conf, iptables! but nothing changed.
my contents is like this :

```
#cat resolv.conf
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4

#iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination    

    nslookup google.com
    ;; connection timed out; trying next origin
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

# dig @8.8.8.8 google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.30.rc1.el6_6.1 <<>> @8.8.8.8 google.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

# dig @8.8.8.8 google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.30.rc1.el6_6.1 <<>> @8.8.8.8 google.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

 # dig @2001:4860:4860::8888 google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.30.rc1.el6_6.1 <<>> @2001:4860:4860::8888 google.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

but now i get it flushed.
thanks

Comment: What does "not working" mean - what error do you get? Your text says `resolv.conf` but your code says `resolve.conf` - if you've edited the filename with an `e` at the end, it won't work...

Comment: sorry, i fixed.

Comment: Verify with your hosting company that they aren't blocking outbound DNS requests. You may need to use their own DNS resolvers.

Comment: Try `dig @8.8.8.8 google.com` and tell us what output you get.

Comment: The output of these three commands might help us understand your problem better: `traceroute -n 8.8.8.8` `traceroute -n -U -p 53 8.8.8.8` `dig @2001:4860:4860::8888 google.com`

Answer (score 1):

Something (ie: an external firewall) is blocking DNS requests. Reach your network admin and explain the situation; it is possible that you had to use an internal DNS.